# Heroku migrate command failing

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, railsapps

I've got an issue when deploying my app to Heroku. I'm running ruby 2.0.0, rails', '3.2.13' and 'pg', '0.15.1'.

I've compiling my assets and am loading environment variables with figaro.

The issue that I am having is that I cannot run the heroku migrate command.

```
Jamies-MacBook-Air:accufly jamieturner$ rake db:reset
Couldn't drop accufly : #<PG::Error: FATAL:  database "postgres" does not exist
>
Couldn't drop accufly : #<PG::Error: FATAL:  database "postgres" does not exist
>
accufly already exists
accufly already exists
-- create_table("roles", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0456s
-- add_index("roles", ["name", "resource_type", "resource_id"], {:name=>"index_roles_on_name_and_resource_type_and_resource_id"})
   -> 0.0071s
-- add_index("roles", ["name"], {:name=>"index_roles_on_name"})
   -> 0.0053s
-- create_table("users", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0163s
-- add_index("users", ["email"], {:name=>"index_users_on_email", :unique=>true})
   -> 0.0042s
-- add_index("users", ["reset_password_token"], {:name=>"index_users_on_reset_password_token", :unique=>true})
   -> 0.0046s
-- create_table("users_roles", {:id=>false, :force=>true})
   -> 0.0057s
-- add_index("users_roles", ["user_id", "role_id"], {:name=>"index_users_roles_on_user_id_and_role_id"})
   -> 0.0037s
-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
   -> 0.0010s
-- assume_migrated_upto_version(20121017180539, ["/Users/jamieturner/Dropbox/Rails/accufly/db/migrate"])
   -> 0.0016s
ROLES
role: admin
role: silver
role: gold
role: platinum
DEFAULT USERS
user: First User
Jamies-MacBook-Air:accufly jamieturner$ heroku run rake db:migrate
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.8314
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- teaspoon/console
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/app/lib/tasks/spec.rake:2:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:425:in `block in load_tasks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:425:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:425:in `load_tasks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:145:in `load_tasks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/app/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
```

My Heroku logs show the following:

```
Jamies-MacBook-Air:accufly jamieturner$ heroku logs
2014-01-13T15:59:19.941147+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.941147+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.941147+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.941147+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.941147+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.941147+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.941147+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.941147+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.941147+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.941646+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:612:in `call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.941646+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.941646+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.941646+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.941646+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.941646+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:42:in `call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.941646+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.941646+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.941646+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.941834+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.941834+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.941834+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.941834+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.941834+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.941834+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.941834+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.941834+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.941646+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.942275+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.941834+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.941834+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.942275+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.942275+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.942275+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.942275+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.942275+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.942275+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__4277113149258428646__call__2252195022539720089__callbacks'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.942275+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.942275+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.942451+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.942451+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.942451+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.942451+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.942451+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.942451+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.942275+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.942892+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.942451+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.942451+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.942451+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.942451+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.942892+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.942892+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.942892+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.942892+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.942892+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.942892+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.942892+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.942892+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.943064+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.943064+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.943064+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.942892+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.943064+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.943064+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
2014-01-13T15:59:19.943064+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-01-13T15:59:19.943064+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-01-13T15:59:19.941791+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/users/sign_in host=secret-badlands-6955.herokuapp.com fwd="213.133.142.4" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=81ms status=500 bytes=643
2014-01-13T15:59:48.932960+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by jamieturner84@hotmail.com
2014-01-13T15:59:54.568601+00:00 heroku[run.8314]: Awaiting client
2014-01-13T15:59:54.615082+00:00 heroku[run.8314]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2014-01-13T16:00:01.203260+00:00 heroku[run.8314]: Process exited with status 1
2014-01-13T15:59:54.336249+00:00 heroku[run.8314]: State changed from starting to up
2014-01-13T16:00:14.160279+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 213.133.142.4 at 2014-01-13 16:00:14 +0000
2014-01-13T16:00:14.165052+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2014-01-13T16:00:14.167083+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.3ms)
2014-01-13T16:00:14.169546+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (0.8ms)
2014-01-13T16:00:14.169784+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
2014-01-13T16:00:14.170019+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 4.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-01-13T15:59:17.268562+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-babb3bda98b37e0587ee7506be68cd38.js host=secret-badlands-6955.herokuapp.com fwd="213.133.142.4" dyno=web.1 connect=16ms service=17ms status=200 bytes=141306
2014-01-13T16:00:14.363847+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-2a320f8efcd905dd4ec269daf6e4a383.css host=secret-badlands-6955.herokuapp.com fwd="213.133.142.4" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=0
2014-01-13T16:00:14.414538+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-babb3bda98b37e0587ee7506be68cd38.js host=secret-badlands-6955.herokuapp.com fwd="213.133.142.4" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=8ms status=304 bytes=0
2014-01-13T16:00:16.903364+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/sign_up?plan=silver" for 213.133.142.4 at 2014-01-13 16:00:16 +0000
2014-01-13T16:00:16.908006+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by RegistrationsController#new as HTML
2014-01-13T16:00:16.908006+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"plan"=>"silver"}
2014-01-13T16:00:16.910808+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms
2014-01-13T16:00:16.912570+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-01-13T16:00:16.912570+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
2014-01-13T16:00:16.912570+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
2014-01-13T16:00:16.912570+00:00 app[web.1]:                                         ^
2014-01-13T16:00:16.912570+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
2014-01-13T16:00:16.912570+00:00 app[web.1]:                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
2014-01-13T16:00:16.912570+00:00 app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2014-01-13T16:00:16.912570+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2014-01-13T16:00:16.912570+00:00 app[web.1]:                AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2014-01-13T16:00:16.912570+00:00 app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
2014-01-13T16:00:16.912751+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2014-01-13T16:00:16.912751+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:6:in `new'
2014-01-13T16:00:16.912751+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-01-13T16:00:16.912751+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-01-13T16:00:16.912751+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2014-01-13T16:00:16.912751+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:36:in `build_resource'
Jamies-MacBook-Air:accufly jamieturner$
```

Any help on where I should look would be much appreciated.

Edit:

My gem file looks like:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end

group :development, :test do
  #gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.12.2", :group => [:development, :test]
gem "database_cleaner", ">= 1.0.0.RC1", :group => :test
gem "email_spec", ">= 1.4.0", :group => :test
gem "cucumber-rails", ">= 1.3.1", :group => :test, :require => false
gem "launchy", ">= 2.2.0", :group => :test
gem "capybara", ">= 2.0.3", :group => :test
gem "factory_girl_rails", ">= 4.2.0", :group => [:development, :test]
gem "teaspoon", ">= 0.7.4", :group => [:development, :test]
gem "bootstrap-sass", ">= 2.3.0.0"
gem "devise", ">= 2.2.3"
gem "cancan", ">= 1.6.9"
gem "rolify", ">= 3.2.0"
gem "simple_form", ">= 2.1.0"
gem "stripe", ">= 1.7.11"
gem "stripe_event", ">= 0.4.0"
gem "quiet_assets", ">= 1.0.2", :group => :development
gem "figaro", ">= 0.6.3"
gem "better_errors", ">= 0.7.2", :group => :development
gem "binding_of_caller", ">= 0.7.1", :group => :development, :platforms => [:mri_19, :rbx]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by adding an if statement to the spec.rake (whichwas being run when using rake db:migrate

```
unless Rails.env.production?
  require 'rake/testtask'
  require "teaspoon/console"

  namespace 'spec' do
    desc "Run the javascript test"
    task :javascript => :environment do
      puts "\n\n===== Starting Javascript Test =====\n\n"
      fail if Teaspoon::Console.new({suite: ENV["suite"]}).execute
      puts "===== Javascript Test Complete =====\n\n\n"
    end
  end

  Rake::TestTask.new(:default => "spec:javascript") do |test|
    test.pattern = 'spec/javascript/*_test.rb'
    test.verbose = true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The line that I'm keying in on is:

`cannot load such file -- teaspoon/console`

Did you `require teaspoon` in your `spec_helper.rb` and/or have `teaspoon` only bundle in your development environment?  If so, changing one of those two will likely fix the problem.

Comment: +1..It's worked my problem was teaspoon only bundle in development environment

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your configuration for teaspoon. You probably want to modify your Gemfile like [this](https://github.com/modeset/teaspoon):

```
group :development, :test do
  gem "teaspoon"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The reset command you're using is local to you system. If you want to do the same on heroku, the syntax is slightly different. Try:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Also, assuming you're using postgres for your db on heroku, you will need:

```
heroku pg:reset <your db name>
```

At which point you will need to re-enter the name of your production db, as this is dangerous, and they 'll want you to be sure you understand what you're doing.